# How ask for user input in a loop in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We want a jenkins job to slowly route traffic from one AWS Route53 Weighted record to another.

How do you ask for user input a for-loop in Jenkins?
I tried something like this, but it just threw a ClassCastException error.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            input {
                message "Shall we start?"
                ok "Yes, we should."
            }
            steps {
                echo "Great!"
                route_traffic()
            }
        }
    }
}
//No NonCPS required
def route_traffic() {
    sh "echo Starting to route traffic..."
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        input {
                message "Continue to route more traffic?"
                ok "Continue"
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review your **input** syntax usage in the scripted method.

Refer to: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/

You can change your **route_traffic()** method to something like this:

```
def route_traffic() {
    echo 'echo Starting to route traffic...'
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        input message: "Continue to route more traffic?", ok: "Continue"
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it! I didn't even see that I was using the scripted input style! Thanks so much, @zedv!!!